# error of Monte Carlo estimate of root mean square speed (vrms) of ideal gas

Tags: monte-carlo, error

I am trying to use Monte Carlo method to estimate the oot mean square speed (vrms) of an ideal gas, the speed of an ideal gas follows the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution:

$$p(v)= \frac{4}{\sqrt {\pi}}(\frac{m}{2k_BT})^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2 \exp({-\frac{mv^2}{2 k_BT}})$$

The Monte Carlo estimate of vrms is:

$ v_{rms} = \sqrt{\bar{v^2}} 
                = \sqrt{\int_0^{\infty} v^2\ p(v)dv} $

So now, we use Monte Carlo to estimate the expectation of the square of the speed $E[v^2]$ and vrms is the square root of the estimate.

I know the error of the estimation of $E[v^2]$ with 95% CI is $1.96 \times \sqrt{\sigma^2/m}$, where m is the monte carlo sample size, and $\sigma^2$ is estimated by $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (v_i^2-\bar{v^2})^2$.

But how about the error of $\sqrt{E[v^2]}$? is it just $s^2= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (v_i - v_{rms})^2$ or $s^2= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (v_i - E[v])^2$ or neither of them? Thanks.

PS: Since $v_{rms}$ cannot have a negative value, is it valid to assume the monte carlo estimate follows a normal distribution when calculating the error? as it is just approximately normal